# Find Nth element from the two unsorted Array

Tags: arrays, sorting, data-structures

Given two unsorted int arrays, find the kth element in the merged, sorted array.
example:
int[] a= [3 1 7]
int[] b = [4 9]
k: 3
return 4 (non-Zero based index)

Please do not provide the straight forward solution where merge two array and sort and find the Nth element. I am looking for more efficient solution i.e using Heap, QuickSort. and make sure arrays are unsorted.

P.S: I know there are many similar questions of above posted in SO but i couldn't find any correct way of implementation in any of them.

Comment: Consider asking the question in [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) as well.

Comment: Assuming a zero indexed array . your merged array is `1 3 4 7 9` so if `k=3`, then you should return `7` and not `4`. Right ?

Comment: yes you are right, let consider as a non Zero based indexed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# code using quick select algorithm:

```
    private void MergeUnsortedArray(int[] A1, int[] A2)
    {
        int[] c = new int[A1.Length + A2.Length];
        int length = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < A1.Length; i++)
        {
            c[i] = A2[i];
            length++;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < A2.Length; j++)
        {
            c[length + j + 1] = A2[j];
        }
        quickselect(c, 0, c.Length, 3);
    }
    private int quickselect(int[] G, int first, int last, int k)
    {
        if (first <= last)
        {
            int pivot = partition(G, first, last);
            if (pivot == k)
            {
                return G[k];
            }
            if (pivot < k)
            {
                return quickselect(G, first, pivot - 1, k);
            }
            return quickselect(G, pivot + 1, last, k);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    private int partition(int[] G, int first, int last)
    {
        int pivot = (first + last) / 2;
        swap(G, last, pivot);
        for (int i = first; i < last; i++)
        {
            if (G[i] < G[last])
            {
                swap(G, i, first);
                first++;
            }
        }
        swap(G, first, last);
        return first;
    }
    private void swap(int[] G, int x, int y)
    {
        int tmp = G[x];
        G[x] = G[y];
        G[y] = tmp;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As it stands your example is wrong.

Assuming its int[] a= [3 1 7] int[] b = [4 9] k: 3 return 7.

Loop through both arrays and push to a `min-heap`. After your done, pop `k` times from the heap and  you will have the `kth (largest)` element from the merged array.

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> minHeap=new PriorityQueue();

for (Integer i : a)
{
  minHeap.add(i);
}

for (Integer i : b)
{
  minHeap.add(i);
}
int count=1;// 1 based index
while(!minHeap.isEmpty())
{

 Integer head=minHeap.poll();
 count++;
 if(count==k)
   return head;

}
```

Code above is untested. But it should roughly look like the above.

Comment: I have modified the question based on your comment, lets say its non-zero based index array. do you have any code to implement the same ?

Answer (score 0):

The general term for this problem is [Selection Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm), which Wikipedia has a great article on.

Finding the kth element of two unsorted arrays is equivalent to finding the kth element of one--just pretend you've concatenated the two. A simple algorithm from the linked page is Quickselect, which is essentially Quicksort but only recursing into the half that contains the kth element. Essentially,

```
Use the first element as the pivot
Iterate over the array, assigning items <= to the pivot to one array, and > to another, until an array has grown large enough that it must contain the desired element
Recurse on that array, offsetting k if necessary
```